# GitHub Markdown: Non-breaking space?

Tags: github, markdown

I'd like to use a non-breaking space in a GitHub `README.md`. I could use either

- the HTML `&nbsp;` (> <) or
- a literal Unicode `U+00A0`, (> <).

Both, like here on StackOverflow, seem to get "sanitized" to a regular space.

Any way to get a non-breaking space on GitHub?